# JQuery Collapse and Expand Code

Tags: jquery, html, css, web

I want to expand boxes on click.
For some reason, the code doesn't work.

http://jsfiddle.net/9UJ7f/1/

PS: I also want the expand to be animated, what do you think is the best way to do this ?
Maybe checking for "expand" and then do an .animate ?

Thx

Comment: it works fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/9UJ7f/2/

Comment: Works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/9UJ7f/3/. You didn't include jQuery in your jsFiddle though.

Comment: What the heck ? jsfiddle seems to have been broken to me, now it works ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you want the header to stay and the content below to expand/collapse.
I think you might want a different approach. jQuery has built in hide() and show(). If you include "fast" or "slow" as arguments, it will add animations.

Comment: thanks for the tip ! So hide() and show would expand the box also, not only change opacity or visibility ?

Comment: Yes, if you create a single div that surrounds the content, you can hide/show that div and leave your header intact.

Comment: You need jquery.animate() for that

Comment: could I also do it like .hide(.content, .time) ?

Comment: @MichaelDibbets .hide(duration) and .show(duration) have built-in animations. http://api.jquery.com/hide/ http://api.jquery.com/show/

Comment: i know, but animate is more flexible if you want sliding, collapsing, folding actions.

Comment: @cocoacoder No, you need to execute a selector first, and then the hide/show methods on the jQuery object returned from the selector. http://api.jquery.com/show/ http://api.jquery.com/hide/

Comment: @MichaelDibbets you said "You need jquery.animate()..." my point is that you don't *need* animate.

Comment: @mawsco Yea true, i concede. but it does give grater flexibility for cooler/more natural effects

Answer (score 3):

On the left side of JSFiddle, you have MooTools selected as your library.

If you open up your javascript console, you'll notice an error message 'jQuery is not defined'.